# Django Link not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to put a link around a piece of table data within a html table.  I get the following result when I look at it in Chrome's Element Viewer.

```
<a href="/tasks/1/"></a>
<a href="/tasks/2/"></a>
<a href="/tasks/3/"></a>
<a href="/tasks/4/"></a>
<table>
...
```

The interesting part about this is that when I look at it in view page source...it comes out correctly wrapped around the

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3"/>
<a href="/tasks/3/">
<td class="tableText">Make a web app</td>
</a>
```

I Cannot think of a good reason why chrome would render this in two different ways.  Is there something I might be doing wrong within my django template?

```
  8 <h1 id="title">Joe's Basic Task List</h1>
  9 <table id="taskTable">
 10 {% for t in taskList %}
 11     <tr>
 12     {%if t.completed == 1%}
 13         <td><div class="btn active"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></t    d>
 14     {%else%}
 15         <td><div class="btn"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></td>
 16     {%endif%}
 17         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{t.id}}"/>
 18         <a href="{% url 'tasks:detail' t.id%}">
 19             <td class="tableText">{{t.task}}</td>
 20         </a>
 21     </tr> 
 22 {% endfor %}
 23 </table>
```

Comment: You're putting a TD inside of a an anchor and an input inside of a TR and that anchor from before is also raw inside of the tr.  this is wrong https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr - chrome is trying it's best to figure out what you are doing.

Comment: Are you sure `compleated` is not a typo ? do you mean `t.completed` instead ?

Comment: that was a typo but the solution was what Mike described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) a `TR` may only contain a mixture of `TD` or `TH` elements.

Change your template to compensate for this. (also it appears you likely have a typo and meant t.completed)

Possibly:

```
<h1 id="title">Joe's Basic Task List</h1>
<table id="taskTable">
{% for t in taskList %}
    <tr>
    {%if t.completed == 1%}
        <td><div class="btn active"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></t    d>
    {%else%}
        <td><div class="btn"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></td>
    {%endif%}
        <td class="tableText">
            <a href="{% url 'tasks:detail' t.id%}">{{t.task}}</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{t.id}}"/>
        </td>
    </tr> 
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Also consider changing the div's to span or putting the styles directly on the td.  Both display as block elements (well the td is a table-cell display, but will behave similarly as a block level element with styling).

Having divs nested inside of a td just seems wrong as you don't really need it for positioning / styling purposes.